# postman error 419 al intentar hacer la petición post en laravel

Tags: laravel, postman

estoy aprendiendo a programar con el framework laravel, pero, al intentar usar el método post. Como prueba, 
intenté usar un método que no existe

```
Route::post('/usuarios', 'userController@prueba');
```

un método existente

```
Route::post('/usuarios', 'userController@create');
```

llamar al método dentro de la función así

```
Route::post('/usuarios', function () {
    return response()->json([]);
});
```

sin embargo, obtengo siempre el mismo resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bastante extraño, pero podrías agregar más detalles para explicar tu problema ya que puede ser que el navegador no acepte o rechaze las cookies, una instalación errónea o cualquier otra cosa.

Comment: estuve leyendo y al parecer es por culpa del acces_token, pero no sé como agregar este token en postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder hacer uso del método post, laravel necesita un token que normalmente generas en formularios haciendo uso del helper `csrf_field()` ó `csrf_token()` por razones de seguridad. Si no le envías el token, Laravel responderá con el error 419. Si quieres que no pase esto, una opción sería agregar la URL en excepciones en el array `$except` que se encuentra en el middleware `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`.

Pero la verdad es que sólo debes de hacerlo en casos específicos ya que por seguridad NO se recomienda.

Comment: entonces ¿debería poner en el código csrf_field() y de ahí hacer lo que el código necesita?

Comment: @MatthewSeidel Desde postman no lo podrás hacer ya que el método post checará que exista el campo “_token” y lo comprobará con la sesión del navegador, no entiendo para que quieres probar el método, ¿qué es lo que quieres verificar?

Comment: estoy testeando la base de datos para luego pasar a angular, sin embargo, estoy trabajando junto a mis compañeros de la universidad y yo fui el único que tuvo ese problema, los demás si pudieron trabajar sin problemas

Comment: @MatthewSeidel Puedes probar la base de datos usando el método get si no estás enviando ningún dato al servidor, el método post es usado para enviar datos al servidor, si quieres enviar datos haz un formulario y dentro de él manda el token de seguridad.

Comment: ya encontré la solución, es quitar ese token, pero esto solo será usado en fase de desarrollo, cuando esté listo el software, esta validación debe volverse a poner

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf por si quieres revisar cómo agregar el token, por si estás usando ajax ahí también te dice cómo agregarlo.

Answer (score -1):

Se debe comentar la linea `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class`, del archivo `kernel.php` de `App\Http\kernel.php`